# Select Distinct With Multiple Columns

Tags: select, distinct

There are col1 and col2 in a `<dataset>`. For every col1 entry there may or may not be more than 1 rows having different values in col2. If I use Select distinct(col1), col2 from `<dataset>` what result will I obtain?

Answer (score 0):

I am giving simple example using Oracle for demonstration. I am using SCOTT account for executing the command. I have 14 records and 8 cols as:

```
empno ename job mgr hiredate sal comm deptno
```

You know you will find unique empno for every record. Now if you write a command as:

```
select distinct deptno, job from emp order by deptno;
```

You will get records as:

```
DEPTNO JOB
```

---

```
    10 CLERK
    10 MANAGER
    10 PRESIDENT
    20 ANALYST
    20 CLERK
    20 MANAGER
    30 CLERK
    30 MANAGER
    30 SALESMAN
```

This means it will select unique deptno and in each deptno if there is one distinct job den the job and the respective deptno will be shown. It gives the distinct job in each departments.